# Hot to Smartphone web programming

Tags: smartphone

I need to build my first web app for smartphones. I want this web app to work with iphone and android.
The question is how to do it :) ? I'm an experienced web developer with microsof dev tools + jquery, but I don't know how to start doing the same for smartphones.
Should I use microsoft tools? Java? Html5?

Thanks.

Comment: The server-side technology is probably not the big factor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Look If you want to create it in way it works on smartphones then you
>   should obviously work using some cross platform or platform
>   independent technology and as its a web app then you have an advantage
>   to use html5 and jquery (mobile plugin).

**I would also recommend to go through `phonegap` that is a library provided to make applications those have to work cross platform on various OS's with minor tweaks. Make sure your requirements are met by the `phonegap` library specs.**

Comment: Can I program with asp.net using html5 and jquery mobile, then use PhoneGap?

Comment: end of the day you have to use html5 and jquery so its your call completely , these both can be used with any technology.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) framework for mobile web app.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a long time, I wanted to share few good links with you guys:

1. http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/01/18/my-workflow-for-developing-phonegap-applications/
2. Nice editor: http://www.mobjectify.com/edit/ + tutorial about it: http://www.mobjectify.com/tutorials/HTML_5_mobile_web_app_from_start_to_finish/

My conclusions are to for sure use PhoneGap and build the web site with html5, jquery mobile, css3 and javascript.